# Преобразование перспективы для осей изображения

Tags: python, opencv

Есть крайние точки лица, оно повёрнуто(не в анфас), по точкам можно найти оси лица ox oy. Нужно преобразовать точки так, чтобы они были в положении, как будто лицо находится в анфас (ox и oy перпендикулярны)
Как это сделать? Я предполагаю, что с помощью perspectiveTransform, и всё же мне нужен совет

Answer (score 1):

Для построения матрицы перспективного преобразования нужно знать координаты четырёх неколлинеарных точек на искажённом изображении, и координаты соответствующих им точек на плоскости. [Пример](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/), когда соотнести легко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие данные имеются?

Кроме того, учтите, что трехмерность лица внесёт свои погрешности.

Comment: попробую сам их написать, есть данные о размерах лица, так что до конечного изображения я пропишу точки, исходя из того, что оси долгов быть перпендикулярны

Comment: окей, я всё-таки не разорался с этими 4 точками. Я не знаю длинны и ширины лица, вы знаете какой-нибудь способ решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Тоже мучаюсь с этим. Нашел более-менее, но как его лепить, ещё тот вопрос.  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/non-affine